# Executing php class files in command line

Tags: php, class

I am new to OOP concept in php. I created two files p1, p2 here. From p1 I am passing two parameter to p2. I have echoed few results. But when I run it, it does not show any result.

I tried in this way:

```
php p1.php
```

in command line ,also

```
php p1.php p2.php
```

But it does not show any result. Where I am making mistake here?

p1.php

```
<?php
require_once('p2.php');
abstract class p1{
        private $resultSet;
        private $matches;
        function __construct(){
        }
        var $text = "This is testing app";
        var $words = "testing";

        abstract public function get($text, $words);
        public function pushToResultSet(array $matches)
        {
                        if(sizeof($matches[0])){
                                foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                                        echo $match;
                                        $this->resultSet[] = $match;
                                }
                        }
        }

        public function getResultSet(){
                echo $this->resultSet;
                return $this->resultSet;
        }
}
?>
```

p2.php

```
<?php

class p2 extends p1{
        //var $text = "This is testing app";
        //var $words = "testing";
  function get($text, $words)
  {
        $pattern = "~\b((?:([a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}))?(www\d{0,3}[.])?(?<!@)[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»\"\"''])?)~ie";
        //echo $text;
      preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
      $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
  }
}

?>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

p1.php

```
<?php
require_once('p2.php');
abstract class p1{
        private $resultSet;
        private $matches;
        function __construct(){
        }
        public function get($text, $words);
        public function pushToResultSet(array $matches)
        {
                        if(sizeof($matches[0])){
                                foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                                        echo $match;
                                        $this->resultSet[] = $match;
                                }
                        }
        }

        public function getResultSet(){
                echo $this->resultSet;
                return $this->resultSet;
        }
}
?>
```

p2.php

```
<?php

class p2 extends p1{
  function get($text, $words)
  {
        $pattern = "~\b((?:([a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}))?(www\d{0,3}[.])?(?<!@)[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/?)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»\"\"''])?)~ie";
        //echo $text;
      preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
      $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
  }
}
    $instance = new p2();
    $instance->get("This is testing app", "testing");


?>
```

I executed both

```
php p1.php
php p2.php
```

But no result.

Comment: You are only loading files and nothing else...

Comment: I don't think that it should be closed because it is a question about a basic concept in oop that many beginners may need its topic. **I recommend to stop holding it and keep it opened.**

Comment: I also dont understand why these people are so keen to close this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a class doesn't actually cause anything to happen, it just defines the class. If you want to use the class you need to create an instance of it, and probably call a method on it. If you put at the end of p2.php the following lines it will probably do what you're expecting.

```
$instance = new p2();
$instance->get("This is testing app", "testing");
```

It seems a bit odd that you're defining the two variables in the class. I suspect that you want them to be the input to the get method. The arguments for methods are not taken from the object, but passed as with any function by the caller. If you wanted to use variables from the object you wouldn't need to put them in the method signature, you could just refer to them as $this->text .

I think you've misunderstood the point of an abstract function too. You don't need to define an abstract function in the superclass unless you want to call it from that superclass. Just defining a new function in the subclass is fine. Abstract functions are useful when you want to define most of a class, but not a crucial bit of functionality. Subclasses provide that functionality, but users of the class only need to know about the superclass. This is useful if you want someone else to be able to write the abstract method in for you, but you still want to be able to interact with the class in your own code.

Comment: thanks for description, Can you please standrize the code in your answer removing the unnecesary part? That will help me to understand better. Here I have checked various tuts and created above code

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I'm saying that you can just add the lines I've given to the end of your p2.php file (after the closing } of the class, but before the ?>), and that the lines in p1 defining the two 'var' variables and the abstract function, can be omitted, although this doesn't change the functionality. Also, p1 won't need to be an abstract class if it doesn't have any abstract methods.

Comment: Do I need to include p1.php in p2.php?

Comment: I was willing to know that how exactly code is written and executed in this program. So I really appreciate if you can modify my code and put it in your answer

Comment: I have described exactly the changes you need to make. I think it would help you more to understand what I've said and make the changes yourself than for me to make them for you. If there's anything you don't understand then ask and someone will explain.

Comment: I updated code, can you please review it

Comment: That looks right to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initiate an object from your class. In p2.php do the following after class:

```
$ob = new p2;
 $ob->get("I am good", "good");
```

This will printout "I am good"
[image]